# How to connect multiple client to single server in C#

Tags: c#, network-programming

i have a two application one is the tcpclient and another is the tcp server .i am sending the string as a data from tcpclient to tcp server. all works fine in case of a single client but when i try to run the another client from different machine i am getting the exception "connection forcible cloased by the remote host" please help me on this how should i connect multiple client to single tcp server here is my code.

```
/*TCP SERVER*/
   static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //192.168.0.105
            IPAddress ipAd = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.100");
        // use local m/c IP address, and 
        // use the same in the client
            FileStream f = File.Open("D:/GPSResearchandDevelopment/GPSService/GPSService/abc.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
            IAsyncResult a = null;
            connection:
            Console.WriteLine("reCHED TO THE CONNECTION");

            TcpListener myList = new TcpListener(ipAd, 8001);


            myList.Start();


            Console.WriteLine("The server is running at port 8001...");
            Console.WriteLine("The local End point is  :" +
                              myList.LocalEndpoint);
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection.....");

            Socket s = myList.AcceptSocket();

            Console.WriteLine("Connection accepted from " + s.RemoteEndPoint);

            byte[] b = new byte[100];
            int k = s.Receive(b);

            Console.WriteLine("Recieved...");

            a = f.BeginWrite(b, 0, b.Length, null, null);
            f.EndWrite(a);

            String[] str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(b).Split('|');
            for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
                Console.WriteLine(str[i]);

            ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
            s.Send(asen.GetBytes("The string was recieved by the server."));
            Console.WriteLine("\nSent Acknowledgement");

            //s.Close();
            myList.Stop();

            goto connection;


        }
/*TCP CLIENT*/

 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        CONNECTAGAIN:
            TcpClient tcpclnt = new TcpClient();

            Console.WriteLine("Connecting.....");


            tcpclnt.Connect("192.168.0.100", 8001);
            // use the ipaddress as in th1e server program

            Console.WriteLine("Connected");
            Console.Write("Enter the string to be transmitted : ");

            String str = Console.ReadLine();
            //String str = "supriya|laxman|medankar";
            Stream stm = tcpclnt.GetStream();

            ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] ba = asen.GetBytes(str);
            Console.WriteLine("Transmitting.....");

            stm.Write(ba, 0, ba.Length);

            byte[] bb = new byte[100];
            int k = stm.Read(bb, 0, 100);

            for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(Convert.ToChar(bb[i]));


            }

            tcpclnt.Close();
//            Console.ReadLine();
            goto CONNECTAGAIN;
        }
```

Comment: Do you want multiple connections AT THE SAME TIME? In this case you'd need some parallel running thread that accepts the incoming connection attempts.

Comment: In short you need to create and maintain a socket and thread for every client. The code you have as it is written will only ever allow for one connection at a time. The receive call should be made on the separate thread since it is a blocking call.

Comment: yes i want multiple connection @ same time

Answer (score 0):

Basically the most of what the main thread should do is

```
create a server socket //TcpListener mylist

while(true)
    listen for new connection and create a client socket //Socket s
    spawn thread to handle client socket connection
```

You should encapsulate the spawned thread in a class so you can store the socket as a member for easy access and cleanup.

The thread you spawn/create should run the logic that interacts with the client.

ie. all of this code.

```
 Console.WriteLine("Connection accepted from " + s.RemoteEndPoint);

            byte[] b = new byte[100];
            int k = s.Receive(b);

            Console.WriteLine("Recieved...");

            a = f.BeginWrite(b, 0, b.Length, null, null);
            f.EndWrite(a);

            String[] str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(b).Split('|');
            for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
                Console.WriteLine(str[i]);

            ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
            s.Send(asen.GetBytes("The string was recieved by the server."));
            Console.WriteLine("\nSent Acknowledgement");

            //s.Close();
            myList.Stop();
```

If you do it this way you can continuously listen for new client connections independent of the interaction between other clients.

Answer (score 0):

You can use socket on the place of tcpclient